# How to make the enemies attack the turret in waves?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the goal is generating randomly enemies and each time the enemies randomly will try to attack the target. the target is my turret I have.

the problem is that it's creating each time a new enemy but the enemies just moving up down at place and never move to the target(turret).

I want the enemies to move around the turret like flying or just moving around in circles or in other psth/s and from time to time the enemy/ies should attack the turret by moving closer to the turret either as group/s or single enemy in wave/s.

but instead the enemies in places just moving up down like ping pong.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TurretTargeting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject targetPrefab;
    public float targetSpawnRadius = 50f;
    public float targetSpeed = 10f;
    public float targetAttackChance = 0.1f;
    public float targetAttackHeight = 10f;
    public float targetAttackWaveFrequency = 1f;
    public float targetAttackWaveAmplitude = 5f;

    private List<Transform> targets = new List<Transform>();

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnTargets());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnTargets()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Vector2 randomCircle = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * targetSpawnRadius;
            Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3(randomCircle.x, 0f, randomCircle.y);
            GameObject target = Instantiate(targetPrefab, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            targets.Add(target.transform);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1f, 3f));
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        foreach (Transform target in targets)
        {
            Vector3 direction = transform.position - target.position;
            float distance = direction.magnitude;
            if (distance > targetAttackHeight && Random.value < targetAttackChance)
            {
                StartCoroutine(AttackTarget(target));
            }
            else
            {
                target.Translate(direction.normalized * targetSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator AttackTarget(Transform target)
    {
        float time = 0f;
        Vector3 startPosition = target.position;
        while (time < targetAttackWaveFrequency)
        {
            time += Time.deltaTime;
            float wave = Mathf.Sin(time * Mathf.PI * 2f / targetAttackWaveFrequency) * targetAttackWaveAmplitude;
            target.position = startPosition + Vector3.up * wave;
            yield return null;
        }
        target.position = startPosition;
    }
}
```

screenshot of the script settings in the editor:

[enemies settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw2vx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I can't sure what's wrong, because I don`t see you full project.
However, from your script, it seems that in the "update" function, only executed the "Attacktarget" function.
I think you must use "Monobeheavior". You can use the debug mode and check the every parameter using break point.
I think you must check these parameters such as distance and random.value.

```
 if (distance > targetAttackHeight && Random.value < targetAttackChance)
{
...
}
```

And then I suggest that dividing the character and enemies side by side.